# System settings on MAC gives error for HTML

Tags: html

I just started to learn HTML and I am using a MAC and using Sublime as my text editor. I have written 6 lines of HTML code but unfortunately it gives this strange symbol output on my browser-what could be the problem? I think it has to do with either my system or browser settings on my computer.

[My output on my Chrome/Safari Browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFEr9.png)

[My basic HTML code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8vpEl.png)

Any advice would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: ensure you are saving as utf-8

Comment: Hi, it's saved as UTF-8 and we tested this on another Mac and her's was working fine so I think it has something to do with my system settings? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's an encoding problem. You have to set the correct encoding in the HTML head via meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"; charset="UTF-8">
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! It turns out it was a whitespace issue. After I couldn't get it to work the first time in TextEdit, I copy and pasted the code into Sublime and it must have carried some invisible stuff with it. But it works now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your default encoding is set to UTF-8.

Below is the snippet from the default settings.
You need to add this to your user settings.

Go to your User Settings: `Preferences > Settings - User` and paste the snippet.

```
// Encoding used when saving new files, and files opened with an undefined
// encoding (e.g., plain ascii files). If a file is opened with a specific
// encoding (either detected or given explicitly), this setting will be
// ignored, and the file will be saved with the encoding it was opened
// with.
"default_encoding": "UTF-8",
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! It turns out it was a whitespace issue afterall. After I couldn't get it to work the first time in TextEdit, I copy and pasted the code into Sublime and it must have carried some invisible stuff with it. But it works now thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the whitespace first and see if there are any invisible characters being added. If that doesn't work, check the encoding of your file. Its possible you have a charset issue. Another thing you could do is try using another editor and/or another browser to see if the errors persist there as well. That will help you find out the source of the problem easier if charset or invisible characters aren't the issue.

Check here.

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_charset.asp

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! It turns out it was a whitespace issue afterall. After I couldn't get it to work the first time in TextEdit, I copy and pasted the code into Sublime and it must have carried some invisible stuff with it. But it works now thanks!

Comment: Happy to be of help AprilQ. Best of luck coding!